# Change linked URL (logo) based on store

Tags: magento-1.9

I'd like my logo to link to my homepage / when on my Indonesian side and the /en/ page when on the English side of the site. This is the code right now:

```
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>" class="logo"><img width="170" height="65" src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>" /></a></h1>
```

What happens is the logo automatically links to /id/ which isn't my homepage. I've decided to go with the root as my homepage.

So essentially the problem is that on the Indonesian side everything links to /id/ when I want it to link to /

What is the php code that I have to replace

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>
```

with to make that happen?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**No need code level changes:**

Just do it from admin settings:

```
Admin->System->Configuration->General->Web-> Add Store Code to Urls-> Set to YES
```

Comment: It is set to YES.. I think you misunderstand the question.

Problem is that the Indonesian side is /id/ for every page EXCEPT for the homepage.